# bind two dataframe in r and fusionnate two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello I have 2 dataframe such as

**df1**

```
COL1 total 
A    23
B    76
C    89
D    29
E    9
F    2
```

**df2**

```
COL1 total 
A    2
B    9
C    1
D    21
E    5
F    1
```

And I would like to bind the two dataframe and fusionnate the two `total` columns such as :

**df3**

```
COL1 total 
A    23(2)
B    76(9)
C    89(1)
D    29(21)
E    9(5)
F    2(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You can bind data by rows and summarise using `toString()` in order to arrange values. Finally, you can clean the data to get the expected order using `mutate()`, `gsub()` and `paste0()`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- df1 %>% bind_rows(df2) %>%
  group_by(COL1) %>%
  summarise(total=toString(total)) %>%
  mutate(total=gsub(', ','(',total),
         total=paste0(total,')'))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  COL1  total 
  <chr> <chr> 
1 A     23(2) 
2 B     76(9) 
3 C     89(1) 
4 D     29(21)
5 E     9(5)  
6 F     2(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a basic R code, here a possible solution:

```
data.frame(COL1=df1$COL1,total=paste(df1$total,"(",df2$total,")",sep=""))
```